# nested array type C++

Tags: c++

In general the type of a C++ array can be written as

```
std::array<T, Size>
```

What happens if my array happens to be a 3x3 array like this:

```
std::array<int> a[3][3];
```

How would the type here look like? I have tried:

```
std::array<int,3,3> or std::array<int, (3,3)>
```

But the compiler doesn't like that.

Comment: `std::array<int> a[3][3];` this won't compile you need to provide the size

Comment: You seem to be confusing C style arrays with std::array. If you want a multidimensional array in C++, you can either do it in C style by saying `int a[3][3]` or use std::array and say `std::array<std::array<int,3>, 3> a`.

Comment: @LakshayGarg What would the type of the C style array be?

Comment: Do you mean to ask the type of `a` in `int a[3][3]`? If so, then the type of `a` is `int[3][3]`.

Answer (score -1):

I'd guess that the type of your variable would be:

```
std::array< std::array<int,3>, 3 >
```